# Wordpress App not scrolling

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, themes

I have built an app for ios and android with wordpress, appPresser and phonegap. I have uploaded the app but the issue I am having is the app does not scroll, the mobile web page scrolls fine but not the app. I contacted appPresser and they tell me it is a theme issue and that i have to use one of their pricey paid themes. Does anyone know of a theme that will work with my app or any suggestions on how to fix the scroll issue within the theme I am using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved with a change to the css:

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
#page{position:absolute;overflow:auto;height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Comment: This did the trick, obviously #page needs to be changed for whatever the wrapper is.

Comment: Is there a way to target this only to app presser? Media queries don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify this for smartphones specifically without affecting, use a media query but for Android 6 and AppPresser2, max-device-width doesn't work.. so

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-width: 480px) {

   html {height:100%;}
   body {height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
   #wrapper {position:absolute;overflow:auto;height:100%;width:100%;}

}
```